# Error when instantiating android:name="app.AppControlleler" in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I get this error message"Cannot resolve file 'app.AppController'" in AndroidManifest.xml. I have a package named app which contains some volley code for https. Whenever clicking the 'app.AppController', i am redirected to the class but still i get an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blueflair.incre">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="app.AppController"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/OwnTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
           android:name=".RegisterationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/OwnTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseInterestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_interest" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/OwnTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.blueflair.incre.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Change_Password"
            android:label="Incre"
            android:theme="@style/OwnTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Change_Phone_Number"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/OwnTheme" >
       </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the "AppController" class

```
package com.blueflair.incre;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `app.AppController` with `.AppController`

Comment: write fully qualified class name for the application class

Comment: you should choose the package where your class exist ... package_name.AppController

Comment: Thx everyone for answering the quesiton. @krystian71115 yes I did try this with the full qualified class name but still not working. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.app.AppController
```

when you putting "**.**" `in Application Tag`, it will show you to suggestions and you can add it.Also as `A M` said , you should choose the package where your class exist! `package_name.AppController` For example, here is my `AppController` `PATH`:

`com.client.myapp -> app -> AppController class`

**So for your class**: `com.blueflair.incre.AppController`

Comment: Thx for answering the question. Yes i did try this method(suggestions) alot but still getting an error. Is it because the build gradle. I am tearing my brain because of this error.

Comment: Thx for the patience @AndroidDev. Here's the screenshot (http://oi60.tinypic.com/29o0gua.jpg). I even tried the `.com.blueflair.incre.AppController` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. The problem was deleting the duplicate file named on the app package itself btw THX :)

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah - you are welcome.glad it helps.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your manifest file:

```
<application
        android:name="com.blueflair.incre.AppController"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/OwnTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">
```

So you have to write full package name instead of `app.AppController`

Answer (score 0):

check package name of AppController class.